# Using the CLI how do I get the balances of a Zenon Network address?

Tags: command-line-interface, blockchain, zenon-network

I'm looking for a way to query the Zenon Network api to get the balance of specific addresses. How can this be done via the CLI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the method: ledger.getAccountInfoByAddress (https://testnet.znn.space/#!api.md Under dual-ledger)

When connecting to your node, you can just curl it using:

curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:35997 -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "id": 20, "method": "ledger.getAccountInfoByAddress","params": ["z1qz5p95pa8c6wq9pvfkg642gjv4nnaayx6vhm2w"]}' | jq

Output looks like:

[image]